# How to display "no planned activities" If no div contains the searched text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html page(I have just javascript code to show,hide div):

```
            <div class="rigaTwo">
                <div class="col1">
                    <p class="room">AULA E</p>
                    <p class="where">PIAZZA A</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">09:00 - 13:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">METODI</p>
                    <p class="who">ZAP</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaTwo">
              <div class="col1">
                    <p class="room">AULA D</p>
                    <p class="where">PIAZZA A</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">10:00 - 12:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">PROF</p>
                    <p class="who"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaOne">
                <div class="col1">
                    <p class="room">STUDIO</p>
                    <p class="where">VIALE Europa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">10:00 - 13:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">PROF.SSA</p>
                    <p class="who"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaTwo">
              <div class="col1">
                    <p class="room">AULA F</p>
                    <p class="where">PIAZZA</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">10:00 - 14:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">PROF</p>
                    <p class="who"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaTwo">
                <div class="col1">
                    <p class="room">AULA B</p>
                    <p class="where">PIAZZA</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">11:00 - 14:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">PROF</p>
                    <p class="who"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaTwo">
              <div class="col1">
                    <p class="room">AULA</p>
                    <p class="where">PIAZZA</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">11:00 - 17:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">SPEV</p>
                    <p class="who"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaOne">
                <div class="col1">
                    <p class="room">AULA EUROPA 3</p>
                    <p class="where">VIALE Europa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">14:00 - 18:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">COMUNICAZIONE.</p>
                    <p class="who">CAV</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rigaTwo">
              <div class="col1">
                    <p class="room">AULA A</p>
                    <p class="where">PIAZZA</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col2 half">
                    <p class="when">14:00 - 18:00</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col3">
                     <p class="what">LAB</p>
                    <p class="who">ALBA</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I would like to filter the rooms(Name_of_room

), so you see only the selected room, if any line contains the name of the room display "no planned activities",it's possible?

This is javascript code for hide/show div:

```
javascript:(function(){ 
    $( \".rigaOne\").hide(); 
    $( \".rigaTwo\").hide(); 
    $( \".rigaOne:contains("+title+")\" ).show(); 
    $( \".rigaTwo:contains("+title+")\" ).show(); 
    $( \".room:contains("+title+")\" ).show(); 
}
```

I have a WebView in Android,this code show only div wich contains title,if all div is hidden i'd like to show "no planned activities"

Comment: Can you give a little more information please? How do you know which one is selected? What have you tried so far? Also, please show your JavaScript.

Comment: javascript:(function(){ +
    $( \".rigaOne\").hide();
    $( \".rigaTwo\").hide();
 $( \".rigaOne:contains("+title+")\" ).show();
    $( \".rigaTwo:contains("+title+")\" ).show();
    $( \".room:contains("+title+")\" ).show();
}

I have a web view in Android,this code show only div wich contains title,if all div is hidden i'd like to show "no planned activities"

Comment: Please add it to your question for formatting reasons ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script for this

```
$('p').each(function(){
    if($(this).html() === 'name of the room'){
        $(this).html('no planned activities');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution and it's works:

```
javascript:(function(){ 
    $( \".rigaOne\").hide(); 
    $( \".rigaTwo\").hide(); 
    $( \".rigaOne:contains("+title+")\" ).show(); 
    $( \".rigaTwo:contains("+title+")\" ).show(); 
    $( \".room:contains("+title+")\" ).show();
    var count = $('.room:visible').size();
    if(count<1){                       
        document.write(\"No planned activities\");
    } 
}
```